# dockerfile to run java exiting instantly

Tags: java, docker

I have the following docker file to run my java application

```
FROM gidikern/rhel-oracle-jre

RUN mkdir /application
WORKDIR /application
CMD "java -Dspring.profiles.active=sprofileName -jar my.war --spring.config.location=./application.properties > app.log > 2>&1"
```

and i'm running using docker-compose:

```
 backend_app:
    restart: always
    image: my-app-runner:latest
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - ./app/my.war:/application/my.war:Z
    - ./app/application.properties:/application/application.properties:Z
    - /srv/docker/backend_app/logs:/application/my.log:Z
    tty: true
```

however when i start i get that my app exited with code 0 constantly.

I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Why would `java -jar my.war` work? A `war` is a Web ARchive - designed to be run by a Java EE compatible servlet container. It has a different format for a `jar` and cannot be simply executed by the java command.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the applicatoin works if i run it from command line outside a docker. (it is a war file due to configuration from the pom.xml. It is executable)

Comment: Well, unrelated, but I would strongly suggest against naming it a `.war` if it isn't.

Comment: it will be yes :) but that is unrelated to this issue

Comment: what does "docker  logs backend_app" say?

Comment: Use `docker logs` command to see container logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually with my base image gidikern/rhel-oracle-jre

I tested and even basic commands like ls didn't work..

Switched to openjdk for now and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very probably there's an error in your application. To debug I suggest you to run the container in shell and to execute the java command manually to see what's happening.

In other words:

```
docker run -it --name app-debug my-app-runner:latest /bin/bash
java -Dspring.profiles.active=sprofileName -jar my.war --spring.config.location=./application.properties
```